# Why am I getting this NullReferenceException in DbConnection.Open()?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am using `System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories` to produce a DbProviderFactory for a dynamically-specified database.  One of the supported types is MySQL.  What I want is to be able to connect to the MySQL server using `Integrated Security`.  I am setting the proper key-value for the connection string below, but when I *do not* provide a Username and Password, I always get a `NullReferenceException`.  I am using MySQL 6.9.8.0.

If I provide valid credentials in the two connection string values that you will see commented out, no exception is thrown.  Although at that point I suspect I am no longer really using Integrated Security.  I have tried setting them to both an empty string and to `null`, but the exception is still thrown either way.

The "my.ini" file includes this already:

> # Enable Windows Authentication
>
> plugin-load=authentication_windows.dll

```
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient");
var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

var csb = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
//csb.Add("UserID", "root");
//csb.Add("Password", "root");
csb.Add("Server", _serverName);
csb.Add("Database", _dbName);
csb.Add("Connection Timeout", userVars.DatabaseTimeout);
csb.Add("Default Command Timeout", _commandTimeout);
csb.Add("Ssl Mode", "None");
csb.Add("Integrated Security", true);
csb.Add("Persist Security Info", false);
csb.Add("Pooling", true);
csb.Add("Maximum Pool Size", 200);
csb.Add("Minimum Pool Size", 0);
csb.Add("Sql Server Mode", true);
csb.Add("Ignore Prepare", false);

conn.ConnectionString = csb.ConnectionString;
conn.Open();   //<--- exception is thrown internally, here
```

Executing this code as-is produces a `NullReferenceException` when `Open()` is called.  As I am stepping in code, this exception pops 4 times on the `Open()` line, and then steps (just once) into my enclosing `try-catch` handler as the NRE.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> server=localhost;database=information_schema;connectiontimeout=60;defaultcommandtimeout=60;sslmode=None;Integrated
>   Security=True;persistsecurityinfo=False;pooling=True;maxpoolsize=200;minpoolsize=0;sqlservermode=True;ignoreprepare=False

Stack trace:

> at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlNativePasswordPlugin.MoreData(Byte[]
>   data)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationChange()
>   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.HandleAuthChange(MySqlPacket
>   packet)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean
>   reset)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String
>   authMethod, Boolean reset)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()    at AllMax.Sql.Init()

I have also tried directly using the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` version of this code, but the exception is still thrown when no User/Pass is provided.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like a potential bug in the MySqlClient code.

Comment: This example connection string uses "auth_windows" : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/use-windows-authentication/ the MySQL docs say it is optional - but maybe MySqlClient requires it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-authentication-windows-native.html